# Correlation, and Multicollinearity

Tags: correlation

This is my final attempt to post this, I am sure someone would know more about this problem that I would.

Here is a brief synopsis. I am trying to fit for about 100 $x$'s and a single independent $y$. All of my $x$'s are strongly correlated with each other. So using OLS is out of question. My first attempt to regularize the problem is to use NNLS (non negative least squares).

I used `nnls` in R to fit the NNLS model. What I find is puzzling at least to me. I find a positive weight (obviously) of some $x$'s, when they are actually negatively correlated with my $y$. Albeit this negative correlation is not a very high one, but the algorithm seems to select them, and assign them a positive weight. Am I missing something? Also it favors some $x$'s that actually have a lower positive correlation over some other ones with higher positive correlation. Why would this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the case where $X_1$ and $X_2$ are both positively correlated with each other, and both negatively correlated with $Y$. It is likely that $X_2$ is *positively* correlated with 
$Y - \beta_1 X$. I'm not too familiar with NNLS, but if it is a stepwise algorithm and adds variables sequentially, this could be the cause.

Is there a reason you need positive coefficients? If not, I would recommend an alternative linear approach like Lasso or Elastic Net, both of which are better at dealing with highly correlated variables.

Edit. Another way to look at it:
Although $X_2$ is negatively correlated with $Y$, possibly $X_2$ is positively correlated with $Y|X_1$

Comment: Sure, that also came to me, but I don't think it's a stepwise algorithm. Any other case where this could happen?  Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @dqr It doesn't matter that it's not stepwise, the issue would still apply.

Comment: @Glen_b Hmm how do you mean?. So you mean its normal for it to pick terms that are negatively correlated and assign them positive weights in the final stage?

Comment: The same issue occurs with linear regression, which is also not stepwise. In the case of linear regression, you can see it explicitly if you fit your regression via Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization.

Comment: Got it, I see what you are saying. Thanks a bunch.