# What is the relationship between regression and partial correlation

Tags: regression, correlation, linear, partial-correlation

There is a well-answered question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76815/multiple-regression-or-partial-correlation).

But unfortunately, I don't even understand how the first equation in the answer is derived. Could someone help explain that?

$$\text{Beta:} \quad \beta_{x_1} = \frac{r_{yx_1} - r_{yx_2}r_{x_1x_2} }{1-r_{x_1x_2}^2}$$

What is $r$ here?

Comment: $r_{ab}$ is the correlation between $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Thanks @Glen_b but I am still not sure I understand this equation. I think this $\beta$ is the same as $(X_1^TX_1)^{-1}X_1^TY$, how is this related with the right-hand-side?

Comment: Thanks. @Glen_b I found it [here](http://www.personality-project.org/r/book/chapter5.pdf)

Comment: `how is this related with the right-hand-side?` First, consider the formula (the 1st one [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/44290/3277) which is homologic with the right-hand one but is for $b$, not for $\beta$. Both this and that are found in nearly any book on linear regression. Second, considering X having just 2 columns, "unwrap" algebraically and in scalar (in place of matrix) notation the expression $(X^TX)^{-1}X^TY$; and I'm sure you will arrive exactly at the formula for $b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comment points out, $r_{ab}$ is the correlation between $a$ and $b$.

This equation:
$$\text{Beta:} \quad \beta_{x_1} = \frac{r_{yx_1} - r_{yx_2}r_{x_1x_2} }{1-r_{x_1x_2}^2}$$ 
can be achieved by solving the following equation:

$$
\beta_{x_1} + r_{x_1x_2}\beta_{x_2} = r_{x_1y} \\
r_{x_1x_2}\beta_{x_1} + \beta_{x_2} = r_{x_2y}
$$

where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are two predictors and $y$ is the dependent variable. Solving this above equation set by basic linear algebra will lead to the first equation.

Details can be found in [Chapter 5 Multiple correlation and multiple regression](http://www.personality-project.org/r/book/chapter5.pdf) of [An introduction to psychometric theory with applications in R](http://www.personality-project.org/r/book/) by William Revelle.

Comment: And where do those simultaneous equations come from?