# Does having negative correlation must also have negative coefficients in linear regression?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, regression-coefficients

The data that I have has strong negative correlation with the response variable.

```
var1    -0.3049408      
var2    -0.2874333      
var3    -0.2760590      
var4    -0.2708325      
var5    -0.2697072      
var6    -0.2667927      
var7    -0.2425371      
var8    -0.2406525      
var9    -0.2405309      
var10   -0.2263708
```

But when I added them to the linear models, some of the variables coefficients are positive. My colleague is saying that this doesn't make sense because the correlations are negative and explaining that var 8 has positive coefficients while other variables are -ve doesn't make sense. Is this true? If the model is correct, does it need for the coefficients to be negative if correlations are negative?

Comment: @EDM, yes, it does. Thanks

Comment: More highly relevant thread https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/44279/3277, and this too https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/33888/3277